# Input change value via mousedown (drag) does not work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

It only increase or decrease when the click is pressed and moved from top to bottom, That is normal operation.
I have this script that allows dragging from the Input increment and decrement value, this works well in Firefox but in Chrome does not work correctly, can anyone correct this bug (in Chrome)?

I have problems even with the script. It only works in firefox, but it does not work the same in Chrome.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/iLen/bacx5qem/

Video: http://recordit.co/yW1NUPrXBP (left: chrome / right: firefox)

```
var clicking = false;
$('.vamoAlSubibaja').mousedown(function() {
  clicking = true;  
});

$(document).mouseup(function() {
  clicking = false;  
})
var i = 0;
var y = 0;
$('.vamoAlSubibaja').mousemove(function(my) {
  if (clicking == false) {
    return
  } else {
    // change value
    if (my.pageY <= $(this).offset().top + $('.vamoAlSubibaja').css('width').replace('px', '') / 10) {
      y = parseInt($(this).val()) + 1;
      $('.movestatus').text('plus');
    } else {
      y = parseInt($(this).val()) - 1;
      $('.movestatus').text('minus');
    }
    $(this).val(parseInt(y));    
    i++;
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working because you are assigning the mousemove event to the div, not to the document.

If you want each div to respond independently you need to assign a value to a variable to know which was clicked down. This way when the mouse moves (after clicking down one of the divs) you can assign your function to that specific div.

This demo is only fixing the mousemove so you can see how to solve your main issue.

```js
var clicking = false;
$('.vamoAlSubibaja').mousedown(function() {
  clicking = true;
});

$(document).mouseup(function() {
  clicking = false;
})
var i = 0;
var y = 0;
$(document).mousemove(function(my) {
  if (clicking == false) {
    return
  } else {
    // change value
    if (my.pageY <= $('.vamoAlSubibaja').offset().top + $('.vamoAlSubibaja').css('width').replace('px', '') / 10) {
      y = parseInt($('.vamoAlSubibaja').val()) + 1;
      $('.movestatus').text('plus');
    } else {
      y = parseInt($('.vamoAlSubibaja').val()) - 1;
      $('.movestatus').text('minus');
    }
    $('.vamoAlSubibaja').val(parseInt(y));
    i++;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i>Only when the mouse moves up and down does
    the value change from the input
    (validate min y max)</i>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<input type="text" value="5" class="vamoAlSubibaja" id="change_value_up_down" />
<input type="text" value="5" class="vamoAlSubibaja" id="change_value_up_down2" />

<!-- only ref -->
<span class="clickstatus"></span>
<span class="movestatus"></span>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it was a great solution

Comment: Hello again, as you could validate that it only works when the mouse goes up and down and not to the sides (left / right)

Answer (score 1):

As per the official [DOM Level 3 documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-mousemove)

> In some implementation environments, such as a browser, mousemove events can continue to fire if the user began a drag operation (e.g., a mouse button is pressed) and the pointing device has left the boundary of the user agent.

In this case Firefox continues to fire the mousemove event when the mouse leave the `input` limits, and Chrome doesn't. That's why you should follow the solution by @Alvaro as a reference and use the `document` instead the `input`.

Keep in mind as well that

> Implementations are encouraged to determine the optimal frequency rate to balance responsiveness with performance.

So the effect wont look exactly the same across browsers.

Comment: Very interesting, I was wondering why was it working on Firefox.